# Only last response from async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Consider the following async function which performs some relatively-heavy calculations (just sleeping in this case):

```js
async function heavyFunc(content)
{
    console.log(`Starting ${content}`);
  
    // Sleeping 2 seconds
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  
    console.log(content + " ENDED!");
}

heavyFunc('call 1');
heavyFunc('call 2');
heavyFunc('call 3');
```

When executing this code, you will see all three messages `call 1 ENDED!`, `call 2 ENDED!` and `call 3 ENDED!`.

How to "stop" first two function calls and finish only the last one?

Comment: Are the actual "heavy calculations" async, or do they hog the event loop?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way to stop `async` functions calls once they were done we have to implement somewhat an "id" system and finish async calculations only for the last call.

Here is a simple example:

```js
let asyncId = 0;

async function heavyFunc(content)
{
    asyncId++;
    let id = asyncId;

    console.log(`Starting ${content}`);

    // Waiting 2 seconds (these are your heavy calculations)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

    // If you want you can stop further calculations right here to prevent further resource usage
    if (id !== asyncId)
    {
        console.log(content + " ABORTED!");
        return;
    }

    // Waiting 2 more seconds (these are your further heavy calculations)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

    if (id === asyncId)
    {
        // This is the last call!
        asyncId = 0;
        console.log(content + " ENDED!");
    }
}

heavyFunc('call 1');
heavyFunc('call 2');
heavyFunc('call 3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar but more functional way

```js
// Set wait fn
const wait = t => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t));

// Async body
(async () => {
  //
  //
  // Main job bunction
  //
  const startJob = (str, time) => {
    const internal = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      // Set checker
      const chk = setInterval(() => {
        // If internal trigger
        if(internal.trigger) {
          // Clear int
          clearInterval(chk);
          // Reject job
          console.log(`${str} canceled!`);
          return reject();
        }
      }, 50);
      
      // Do calculation here
      await wait(time);
      
      // Check if not canceled
      if(internal.trigger) return;
      
      // Completed
      console.log(`${str} completed!`);
      resolve(str);
    });
    
    // Extend internal with cancel method
    internal['cancel'] = () => {
    internal.trigger = true;
    }
    
    // Extend internal with trigger
    internal['trigger'] = false;
    
    // return internal
    return internal;
  };
  
  //
  //
  // Workers total
  //
  const wrk = 3;
  
  // Object for current job instance
  let prevJob;
  
  // Run workers
  for(let i = 1; i <= wrk; i++) {
    // If previous job exist, break it
    if(prevJob) prevJob.cancel();
    
    // Start new job
    console.log(`Starting Job ${i}`);
    prevJob = startJob(`Job ${i}`, 1000*i);
    
    // Wait for 0.5 sec
    await wait(500);
  }
})();
```